# In constructor 'Player::Player(std::string, int, Board*)':

Tags: c++, constructor

```
Player::Player(string Playername, int nr ,Board* x)
{
    imie= Playername;
    number=nr;
    int k;

    if(nr==1)
        k=0;
    else k=24;

    for(int i=0;i<UNITS_NUMBER;i++)
    {   Unit figure(figure,i);
        units[i]=figure;

        units[i].move(x->getF(k));
        if(nr==1)
            k++;
        else k--;
    }
}
```

(It's only a constructor of Player class)
and error:

In constructor `Player::Player(std::string, int, Board*)`:

no matching function for call to `Unit::Unit()`

`Player::Player(string Playername, int nr ,Board* x)`

Here is the definition of `Unit`

```
class Unit
{  
    Field* place;
    Unit* unit;
    int name;


public:
    Unit(Unit iam, int n);
    void move(Field* x);
    int getname(){return name;}
};
```

Here is the definition of `Player`

```
const int UNITS_NUMBER = 5;
class Player
{
    Unit units[UNITS_NUMBER];
    string imie;
    int number;

public:
    Player(string Playername, int nr, Board *x);
    string getName();
    void decide(Board*);
    ~Player();
};
```

If u need more, tell me.

After change:

```
class Unit
{  Field* place;
    Unit* unit;
    int name;


public:
    Unit(int n);
    void move(Field* x);
    int getname();
};
```

and `Player`

```
Player::Player(string Playername, int nr ,Board* x)
{
    imie= Playername;
    number=nr;
    int k;
    if(nr==1)
        k=0;
    else k=24;

    for(int i=0;i<UNITS_NUMBER;i++)
    {   Unit figure(i);
        units[i]=figure;

        units[i].move(x->getF(k));
        if(nr==1)
            k++;
        else k--;
    }
}
```

Still thesame error ;/

Comment: what is `units` and how does `Unit` look like?

Comment: There is probably no matching constructor for Unit figure(figure, i). Check that the arguments you have passed are of the same type as what the constructor expects.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FfyLzMRj its unit

Comment: Can you also include you Player class declaration.

Comment: Passing an unconstructed object to itself through its own constructor before it even exists really doesn't make a lot of sense. Even if it worked, you'd get infinite recursion.

Answer (score 3):

Unit doesn't have a copy constructor (so you can't pass it by value).

Also, this is undefined behaviour:

```
Unit figure(figure,i);
```

since the value of `figure` is used before it's initialized.

Comment: @Nudler applying some 'fantasy spray' to compensate for the missing code: http://ideone.com/dq78eM I don't see the problem (well, I see lots of problems, but not "still the same")

Comment: In construktor must be int n-0. And now it's works ;D

Comment: Ah. It's so automatic for me. Yes, you need a default constructor because you're not always calling a sepcific constructor :/

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that the `Unit` constructor, takes a *copy* of `Unit` in it.  However, there is no copy constructor or default constructor for `Unit` so it cannot be constructed.

It's not clear why you want to reference a `Unit` object from within the `Unit` class so it's difficult to suggest a solution.

You also can't declare and refer to a variable in the line:

```
Unit figure(figure,i);
```

Comment: @Nudler wouldn't that be `this` in C++?